# Is it Possible to Connect Docker Containers Through Http Using Http

Tags: docker

I am attempting to use Docker to help deploy an application. The idea is to have two containers. One is the front-end containing Nginx and an Angular app.

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

It is supposed to contact a Spring Boot based API generated using the [gradle-docker plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker) and Dockerfile recommended by [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

They seem to run fine individually (I can access them on my development machine); however, I am having trouble connecting the two.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: com.midamcorp/emp_front:latest
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - app
  api:
    image: com.midamcorp/employee_search:latest
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    networks: 
      - app
networks: 
  app:
```

Based upon my understanding of the Docker documentation on networks, I was under the impression that the containers would be placed in the same network and thus could interact, with the service name (for example, api) acting as the "host".  Based upon this assumption, I am attempting to access the API from the Angular application through the following:

`private ENDPOINT_BASE: string = "http://api:8080/employee";`

This returns an error: `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`.

To be honest, the sample I have looked at used this concept (substituting the service name for host to connect two containers) for database applications not HTTP. Is what I am attempting to accomplish not possible?

EDIT:

My nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
      listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
         location / {       
             index  index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }         

    }

}
```

EDIT:

Updated nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

      upstream docker-java {
        server api:8080;
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


       server {
        listen 8081;
         server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-java;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


}

    server {
      listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
         location / {       
             index  index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }         

    }

}
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: com.midamcorp/emp_front:latest
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    image: com.midamcorp/employee_search:latest
    networks: 
      - app
networks: 
  app:
```

And the client / Angular app uses the following to contact the API `private ENDPOINT_BASE: string = "http://localhost:8081/employee";`

Output from docker ps

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
947eb757eb4b        b28217437313                           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   employee_service_webapp_1
e16904db67f3        com.midamcorp/employee_search:latest   "java -Djava.securit…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                                                  employee_service_api_1
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. However, you do not show your nginx configuration, which is vital here, you also do not show how you invoke your service from outside. A while ago there was a problem with nginx that an upstream had to exist and be reachable when nginx starts when using it as http reverse proxy so the nginx container had to come up last. On top of that a while ago an explicit link from the nginx container to the upstream one was necessary to make it work, even though the feature was deprecated.

Comment: I have added the nginx configuration. I can access the 'api' service simply by typing localhost:8080 in my browser. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, your nginx is not a reverse proxy which would be a standard scenario. So what is its purpose, just to serve javascript for the client to consume? So the URL you provide above: http://api:8080 is not something that you nginx redirects to, but something that client gets delivered from nginx for consumption in JavaScript? If so, your client runs on the host and does not know about the api host and should not actually have access to port 8080 if it knew. Setup a proper reverse proxy _and_ make your client URL to be based on the proxy host:port combination, that is localhost(:80).

Comment: Here is an example of setting up nginx as reverse proxy in a container: https://medium.com/@joatmon08/using-containers-to-learn-nginx-reverse-proxy-6be8ac75a757 and more here http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php

Comment: @OlegSklyar thanks much for your help. I reviewed the article and have made changes to my application but am still getting the same error? Any guidance would be appreciated (the opening post has been updated). To clarify, the nginx in `webapp` is used to serve an Angular app to the client. I do not want `api` to be accessible to the outside world. Thanks again.

Comment: post output of `docker ps` plz

Comment: @AlexKarshin the output has been added to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is not anything weird. It's just that you did not explicitly *name* your containers. Instead, Docker generated a the names by itself. So, nginx *will* resolve `employee_service_api_1`, but will not recognize just `api`. Open you webapp container and take a look at your hosts (`cat /etc/hosts`) - it will show you `employee_service_api_1` and it's IP address.

How to fix it.

Add `container_name` to your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: com.midamcorp/emp_front:latest
    container_name: employee_webapp
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    image: com.midamcorp/employee_search:latest
    container_name: employee_api
    networks: 
      - app
networks: 
  app:
```

I always refrain from using "simple" names (i.e. just `api`), cuz on my system multiple containers with similar names might show up, so I add some prefix. In this case I named the api container `employee_api` and now nginx will resolve to that name once you restart your containers.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. Unfortunately, it is still not working. To clarify, is `employee_api` what I should place in the `upstream` block of my nginx conf or should I be able to access `http://employee_api:8080/employee` directly from the Angular app. Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you are trying to access the api container from another container, you use the name. So to nginx conf it goes as well. After your comment I now suspect you lack basic networking knowledge. I think you should read about `/etc/hosts`.